# What's the difference between Hedges' g and Cohen's d?

Tags: effect-size

I have been reading http://www.polyu.edu.hk/mm/effectsizefaqs/effect_size_equations2.html and the only difference I can find between the two is that they have ever so slightly different pooled standard deviation values but I don't understand how changing these SD values is meant to improve the accuracy of the estimate of effect size.

The differences in standard deviation are the following ($SD_{pooled}$ is the pooled SD for Cohen's d and $SD^{*}_{pooled}$ is for Hedges' g):

$SD_{pooled}=\sqrt{\frac{n_1 SD_1^2+n_2 SD_2^2}{n_1+n_2-2}}$

$SD^{*}_{pooled}=\sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)SD_1^2+(n_2-1)SD_2^2}{n_1+n_2-2}}$

Comment: Related thread: [Difference between Cohen's d and Hedges' g for effect size metrics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1850/930).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, the difference between them is very small and with large $N$ will disappear.  In fact most people (at least in my experience) are not aware of any of this; "[Cohen's $d$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen.27s_d)" is often used generically, many people have not heard of Hedges' $g$, but they use the latter formula and call it by the former name.  The difference is that Cohen used the [maximum likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) estimator for the variance, which is biased with small $N$, whereas Hedges used [Bessel's correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) to estimate the variance.  (For more on this topic, it may help you to read this CV thread: [What is the difference between N and N-1 in calculating population variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/))  The corresponding formulas are often known as the *population* formula for the variance and the *sample* formula.  Recall that these are:
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(X)_\text{population} &= \frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2}{N}  \\
~ \\
~ \\
\text{Var}(X)_\text{sample}     &= \frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2}{N-1} 
\end{align}
As $N$ increases indefinitely, these two estimates will converge to the same value.  However, with small samples, the population formula will *underestimate* the variance because it does not take into account the fact that the mean, $\bar x$, was estimated from the same dataset.  When these estimates are subsequently used to estimate the standardized mean difference, that implies that the former will *overestimate* the effect size.

Thus, with small samples, Hedges' $g$ provides a superior estimate of the standardized mean difference, but the superior performance fades as the sample size increases.