# Using hedge's g from a meta-analysis to calculate required sample size for a paired t-test

Tags: statistical-power, meta-analysis

In [this](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnins.2019.01095/full) meta analysis the authors quote an overall Hedge's *g* effect size of $g=1.116$ for the effect of transcranial magnetic stimulation (TMS) on cocaine and methamphetamine use. Seems dubious to me but I will ignore that for now.

I have been asked by a colleague to calculate the required sample size for a proposed study. The design is quite simple: testing difference in change in number of days per week of drug use from pre- to post-treatment between a control group and a TMS treatment group. I propose to use a simple non-paired *t*-test on change scores to do this.

I know how to calculate the required sample size for this analysis based on Cohen's *d*, but am unfamiliar with Hedge's *g*. From what I read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/difference-between-cohens-d-and-hedges-g-for-effect-size-metrics) there are ways to calculate Cohen's *d* from Hedge's *g*, but there are a few things I don't understand

**(a) I am unclear whether the Hedge's *g* used in meta-analyses to generalise effect sizes across multiple studies is the same as the effect size used in single studies as an alternative to Cohen's *d* for small sample sizes**

**(b) I do not know how to convert the Hedge's *g* effect size of $g=1.116$ to Cohen's *d* since the *N* they refer to in the paper seems to refer to studies rather than subjects**

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: For your purposes, $g = d$. Simply plug it in in place of d & go ahead. If you are doing a power analysis, you solve for N, the N reported in a meta-analysis is a different N--ignore that.

Comment: Thanks @gung, gold advice as usual