# Formula for standardized mean difference in meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, standardized-mean-difference

I am reading the book: Terri D. Pigott. Advances in Meta-Analysis. Springer 2012. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-2278-5

On page 10, there is a formula for standardized mean difference:

[image: Source: Terri D. Pigott. Advances in Meta-Analysis. Springer 2012.]

Is the only error there in the denominator of (2.10) and the line just after the formula?

How can one explain the formula (2.12)?

Comment: See the answers to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/difference-between-cohens-d-and-hedges-g-for-effect-size-metrics I do not see an error in the section you quote, perhaps you need to specify exactly what it is?

Comment: @mdewey Thank you for pointing out the Hedges' g. The error in (2.10) is that $s_p^2$ is variance, not standard deviation, as defined in (2.11).

Answer (score 2):

That's indeed an error. The denominator in (2.10) should be $s_p$, that is, the square-root of $s_p^2$, which is the pooled variance (which is given correctly by 2.11).